# Android Message Queue Per Thread or Per Handler

Tags: android

I am writing my handlers in two different activities which are running on the same UI thread. Now the question is if I post a message using these two different handlers, would it end up in the same message queue associated with the main thread or each handler has a separate message queue associated with it.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at this [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#Handler%28android.os.Looper%29)

Comment: Thanks. MessageQueue is associated with the thread. But what happends in case of multiple handlers. So if I post a message on one handler, then will the handleMessage of both the handlers will be called ?

Comment: Hm :) interesting, I think yes but I'd write a simple app and try it, I think it's the best way to figure it out.
**UPD:** I suppose it implements observer pattern, may be I'm wrong, if so it will notify each handler about message.

Answer (score 1):

Each `Handler` is associated with a `Looper`. A Looper is in turn associated with a `Thread`.

So if you have a single thread, **you'll have a single message queue**.

Check [this link](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/159/android-guts-intro-to-loopers-and-handlers/) for a nice introduction to Loopers & Handlers.